# Why doesn't masonry fill the width of container fully?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-masonry

I'm trying to make mega menu. The sub1 menu must have width based on its content (content is other ul's) but not more than max-width ( so i calculate that width using js). And i want the submenu items to be ordered by masonry. So the problem is masonry doesn't fill the container fully.

```
var maxWidth = $('.parent').outerWidth() -  $('.main').outerWidth();
var ulWidth = 0;
$('.sub1 > li').each( function( index, element ){
        ulWidth = ulWidth + $(this).outerWidth();
});
var ulWidth = Math.round(+ulWidth) + 1;
var width1;
if(ulWidth < +maxWidth) {
  width1 = ulWidth + 'px';
}
else {
  width1 = maxWidth + 'px';
}

$('.sub1').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.maso',
  containerStyle: { 
    position: 'absolute',
    width: width1
    }
});
```

"Prototype" of my megamenu =)

https://jsfiddle.net/2hjwdkum/1/